# Taking values from 2D array vectorized

Tags: python, vectorization

I am having some trouble with the following. I have a M x 2N array (`solution`). I want to take the values and put them into N M x 2 arrays, each stored in a different object in the list `masses`. The code cannot rely on all loops because the program is very slow otherwise. Here is my attempt:

```
        for i in range(len(masses)):
            self.masses[i].l = solution[:len(solution)][2*i: 2*(i + 1)]
```

The problem is, this just takes the entire solution array and puts it in each `l` array. Any ideas why this might be happening?

As an example, say I have 3 objects in the array `masses`. The `solution` input is

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0]
 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 [2,4,6,8,10,12]]
```

The expected values of `l` in each of the objects in `masses` is:

```
self.masses[0].l = [[0,0]
                    [1,2]
                    [2,4]]


self.masses[1].l = [[0,0]
                    [3,4]
                    [6,8]]

self.masses[2].l = [[0,0]
                    [5,6]
                    [10,12]]
```

Instead, each `l` array is just set as the the `solution` array.

Comment: Im not following the question at all, sorry. You're allocating values to new memory, how can it be vectorized?

Comment: Can you give example input and output?

Comment: @roganjosh I have added an example

Comment: What are M and N? I mean, why you said `solution` is Mx2N? Where does the "2" come from?

Comment: @Valentino if you prefer I have an M x N array and want to put it into N/2 lots of M x 2 arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a list comprehension. It's faster than a normal loop.
I do not know what objects are stored inside `masses`, so for the sake of this example let me use `masses` as a simple list.

```
solution = [[0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8,10,12]]

masses = [None] * 3 #I get that its length should be half of the length of the inner lists in solution.
for i in range(len(masses)):
     masses[i] = [j[2*i:2*(i+1)] for j in solution]

print(masses)
```

`masses` is:

```
[
 [[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 4]], 
 [[0, 0], [3, 4], [6, 8]], 
 [[0, 0], [5, 6], [10, 12]]
]
```

Which should be what you want.

Guessing how to use it with your `masses` list, it shoud be:

```
for i in range(len(masses)):
    self.masses[i].l = [j[2*i:2*(i+1)] for j in solution]
```

Just be sure that you have enough objects in your `self.masses` list, or you will get an `IndexError`.

**EDIT after comments**

If `solution` is a Mx2N numpy array, it can be done like this:

```
import numpy as np
solution = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,8,10,12]])
masses = [solution[...,2*i:2*(i+1)] for i in range(int(solution.shape[1]/2))]
```

`masses` is:

```
[
 array([[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 4]]), 
 array([[0, 0], [3, 4], [6, 8]]), 
 array([[0, 0], [5, 6], [10, 12]])
]
```

As I said in the comments, if you use the list comprehension mentioned before it works, but each `masses` entry will be a list of 1D numpy array. Now each `masses` entry is a 2D numpy array.
I am not sure about efficiency, but give it a try: [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) is quite fast.
However if you are dealing with tons of data, at some point you just need to bear with it. There is a limit on optimization.

In your OOP setting, you likely have a method to populate that `self.masses` attribute list. It should be something like:

```
def setmasses(self, solution):
    for i in range(int(solution.shape[1]/2)):
        self.masses[i].l = solution[...,2*i:2*(i+1)]
```

I am afraid there is not easy way to avoid the `for` loop in this case, because you need to loop over a list of already existing objects.

Comment: Thanks very much. Does this work with np.array? Also there an easy way to get rid of the outer loop, given that we are looping through a list of objects? This program will have several thousand objects in the list of masses (and also the other dimension will be large), so if not I may have to get rid of the object oriented stuff completely.

Comment: (I have tested this, and it speeds it up a little bit but not significantly compared to a traditional loop)

Comment: If `solution` is a numpy array, it should be done a bit differently, otherwise it works, but each masses entry will be a list of 1D numpy array. I will edit the answer with the appropriate way.

Comment: @bnosnehpets I edited again, I realized the previous version was not consistent with the way you intended to populate the `self.masses` list.